# could see half list of ip,mac addresses and host name

Tags: windows, mac, powershell, ip, arp

Here is my code, I have tried in power shell, I can see only half list of IP, mac address and host-name, unable to see my manager's IP address while I can see my colleagues IP address.

```
$result = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
(arp -a) -Match '\s\s\d' |
 ForEach-Object {
   $parts = $_.trim() -Split '\s+'
   Try {
     $HostName = ([Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($parts[0])).HostName
   }
   Catch{   
    $Hostname = "No Hostname found"
   }
    $info = [pscustomobject]@{
          IPAddress = $parts[0]
          MACAddress = $parts[1]
          Type = $parts[2]
          HostName = $HostName
    }
      $null = $result.Add($info)
 }  
 $result
```

Comment: Are those IP addresses visible in the original `arp -a` output? Do the addresses actually belong to your subnet or are they in a different subnet?

Comment: yes, i can see the same output in the original ap -a and also the addresses belongs to my subnet...i want to scan all the ip addresses belonging to my subnet as well as different subnet..so is there any way?

Comment: [Get-NetNeighbor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netneighbor?view=win10-ps) will output the Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) cache.

Comment: @jfrmilner I can see more no. of ip addresses but it's in a range between 172.17.88.*-172.17.95.*.......I can't see the ip addresses after 95...and my manager's ip address is  172.17.96.* (in this range)...how can I get this addresses in this range?

Comment: The ARP cache will only contain entries for addresses its resolved, if your computer has not interacted with your managers computer it'll not be present. If you're trying to scan your local network then `nmap` would be the common choice. Please update the question with the goal you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @jfrmilner   I tried nmap too..but still got the same.........is it because of different broadcast domain, I couldn't see his ip address?

Comment: Give all the possible IP addresses in your subnet a ping and then run your command and see what the result is. Creating a PowerShell script to ping 1-254 is rather simple and just trivial and you seem to be able to figure out how to use PowerShell.